# How to remove Word styles when inserting by Ctrl+V in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, wysiwyg

I want remove styles when i paste text from word by Ctrl+V.
how to do this?

i have

```
forcePasteAsPlainText: true
```

but

> Note: paste from word is not affected by this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button function ["Paste from MS Word (with cleanup)" ] *should* clean all those extra ms word tags.

I found [fix](http://www.billyswebdesign.com/blog...-wysiwyg-that-can-clean-a-paste-from-ms-word/) for nicedit, but I havent tested it yet, hope itll work.